# How to add comments inside a post like we do when coding?

Tags: support, markdown

When we code we can write things like

```
// This line will be ignored by compiler
// TODO: Implement blah blah blah
```

And when I post on SE sometimes I want to add comments so that people who edit my post will see

```
Content blah blah blah
// Add supporting facts if possible
More content blah
```

and people who view my post but do not edit will only see

> Content blah blah blah
>   More content blah

This feature will be specially helpful if I want to inform further editors of something, e.g. possible improvements that I've not yet merged into the post. Is it possible to do this?

---

<sup>Well, using the <sup> tag may be a workaround, but I don't want it as viewers can also see this.</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Markdown [supports some HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/307988) so you can use HTML comments...

```
<!-- like this! --->
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of HTML yet...